# Count a Field based on Date Greater Than

Tags: javascript, datetime, filter, count, reduce

I'm trying to filter a collection by datetime > current year and then count the number of "Event Waivers" on a ReasontimeOff field.

The filter/count works when I tried using another parameter, but can't seem to be able to compare it by date. Can anyone help? Appreciate the help in advance. Thanks!

```
    <% var test = employee.discussions.filter(({datetime}) => datetime > "2017-02-13T15:21:00.000Z")
    .reduce(function (n, reason) {
            return n + (reason.reasontimeoff == 'Event Waiver');
        }, 0); %>

    <div> <%= test %> </div>
```

Comment: You need to convert to timestamp to compare 2 date like `new Date(datetime).getTime() > new Date("2017-02-13T15:21:00.000Z").getTime()`

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked!!! Thank you so much!